# JS FileReader removes quote marks from .csv file

Tags: javascript, file, csv, filereader

I'm trying to read a .csv file which contains quote marks around values that have commas in them. Here's the code:

```
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = this.onFileLoad.bind(this);
  fileReader.readAsText(this.fileInput.files[0], "CP1252");
```

When I inspect `event.target.result` in `onFileLoad`, I can see that all the quote marks have disappeared. This makes it impossible to identify the values in the text, as those commas that were inside quote marks will be mistaken for separations of values. Why is this happening?

Comment: With apologies, `FileReader` [isn't broken](https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips). :-) The problem is elsewhere and it just seems like `FileReader` is doing that. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (including sample CSV text), ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). (Though it's really awkward to use `FileReader` in Stack Snippets. :-( )

Comment: If FileReader isn't doing that, it must be the input element? I don't see any other options, do you?

Comment: I don't think it's either `FileReader` or the `input` element. I think the source data doesn't have quotes in the file being read. I realize you've said it does, but if `FileReader` or `input`s were broken in such a fundamental way, it would be well-known. They're **extremely** thoroughly tested and battle-hardened (that's the point The Pragmatic Programmer is making with the "`select` is not broken" story).

Comment: First step: try to open your csv in a code editor, not in something that knows how to read csv. Second step check the encoding really is cp1252?

Comment: FWIW, [here's how to demonstrate a problem using `FileReader` in a Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396933/how-do-you-use-filereader-or-a-web-worker-or-similar-that-needs-an-external-fi).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Just for the record, I never meant to claim that FileReader is broken. I know the title suggests it, but I really just described what seemed to be happening (Quote marks are in Excel, the file goes through file reader, the quote marks are gone) so I could get some guidance.

Comment: Anyway, @Kaiido suggested that I tried to open the file elsewhere, and I can now see that there are in fact no quote marks in the file. I wasn't aware that Excel added those automatically. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's just the idiomatic phrase The Pragmatic Programmer used. :-) Glad you figured it out!!